# Python executable created with PyInstaller doesn't run

Tags: python, matplotlib, executable, pyinstaller

I have a simple script in order to plot a ROC curve (using `sklearn` and `matplotlib`). I used `PyInstaller` to create an executable from this script. The script itself runs and works perfectly but the executable gives me this error:

> No module named 'tkinter'

What I tried:

1) Re-create the executable without the `--onefile` flag (in case any .dll was missing) (FAILED)

2) Manually import `tkinter` inside my script (FAILED)

Actually when I added `import tkinter` the error changed to (in case it matters):

> No module named 'tkinter.filedialog'

I am confused. I used `PyInstaller` many times but it's the first time I encounter this kind of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the [.spec](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html) file and put the path to the module inside 'pathex' (on Analysis). You can discover the correct module path using `module.__file__`.
In your case:

```
>>> import tkinter.filedialog
>>> tkinter.filedialog.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/filedialog.py'
```

On .spec file:

```
 a = Analysis(['main.py'],
                 pathex=['/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/'],
                 binaries=None,
                 datas=None,
                 hiddenimports=[],
                 hookspath=[],
                 runtime_hooks=[],
                 excludes=[],
                 win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
                 win_private_assemblies=False,
                 cipher=block_cipher)
```